# How to get my Java program to communicate with process it makes via System.in System.out

Tags: java, input, process, io, output

I'm trying to make a AI programming game where my Game Engine will send the game state to another Java program in the form of a string, and then wait for up to 2 seconds to receive a another string back containing the information of the move the program wants to make.

However, I'm having trouble getting constant communication between the two programs. I can send information, then receive information, but then the process just stalls out. Any advice?

The User's code must communicate through System.in and System.out, but what I do on the engine's end can be whatever.

```
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process compileOne = rt.exec("javac PlayerOne/Main.java");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    System.out.println("Compiled");
    Process process = rt.exec("java PlayerOne/Main");
    OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream(); // <- Eh?
    InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));
    while(true){
        writer.write("SENDING TO CHILD \n");
        writer.flush();
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + line);
        }
    }
}
}

public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    System.out.println("SENDING TO OG PROCESS");
    Random r = new Random();
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        String received = console.nextLine();
        System.out.println("CHILD RECEIVED: " + received);
        System.out.println(r.nextInt());
    }
}
}
```

But here's my output:

```
Compiled
RECEIVED: SENDING TO OG PROCESS
RECEIVED: CHILD RECEIVED: SENDING TO CHILD
RECEIVED: -800346246
```

Comment: Have you considered using `Socket`s instead?

Comment: `BufferedReader` is waiting for a "end of line" terminator, but `nextInt` will never send one

Comment: @MadProgrammer Wouldn't the "ln" of "println" send the "end of line" terminator? (the \n)

Comment: That’s a reasonable assumption, but it still seems to be a point of failure